# If $2\tan^{-1}x + \sin^{-1} \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$, find the values for $x$ for which the function is independent of $x$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

For $x>1$, then
$$2\tan^{-1} x = \pi -2\sin^{-1} \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

For $x<-1$

$$2\tan^{-1} x =-\pi -2\sin^{-1} \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

So $x\in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$

But the given answer is only $(1,\infty)$

Is there any specific reason why we don’t consider the left part, or is it just a mistake?

Comment: It looks like a mistake to me. But the idea of a set of values over which a function is independent of $x$ is in any case rather dubious. After all, its value on $(1,\infty)$ is not the same as its value on $(-\infty,-1)$, so it can't really be said to be independent of $x$ on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$. I would say the question is ill-posed.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Moreover, you face an odd function. Then $\to +1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct! It's vividly seen in the graph below:

[image]